# Stop repeatActionForever in Sprite Kit swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I created an SKAction that repeatsForever (it's the planet spinning). But I want to stop it once the lander lands on the landing pad. So far my code is not working. I tried both removeAllActions() and removeActionForKey as you'll see. The contact detection works just fine, and there's a bunch of code not shown which includes the collision delegate, etc.

```
  func createPlanet() {
    var planet = SKSpriteNode()
    planet.zPosition = 1
    planet.name = "mars"

    redPlanet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "redPlanet")
    redPlanet.name = "red"
    redPlanet.zPosition = 2
    redPlanet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: redPlanet.texture!, size: size)
    redPlanet.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    redPlanet.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = planetMask
    redPlanet.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = 0
    planet.addChild(redPlanet)

    landingPad = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "landingPad")
    landingPad.name = "pad"
    landingPad.zPosition = 3
    landingPad.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: redPlanet.size.height / 2 - 60)
    landingPad.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: landingPad.size)
    landingPad.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    landingPad.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = landingPadMask
    landingPad.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = landerMask
    landingPad.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = landerMask
    planet.addChild(landingPad)

    planet.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: -redPlanet.size.height / 6)

    let spinner = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration: 3)
    planet.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(spinner), withKey: "planetSpin")

    addChild(planet)
  }
```

And this...

```
  func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    if !hasLanded {
      if contact.bodyA.node!.name == "lander" {
        hasLanded = true
        print("bodyA contact")
        physicsWorld.speed = 0
        removeAllActions()
        removeActionForKey("planetSpin")
      } else if contact.bodyB.node!.name == "lander" {
        print("bodyB contact")
        hasLanded = true
        physicsWorld.speed = 0
        removeAllActions()
        removeActionForKey("planetSpin")
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not removing actions from the planet node, you're removing them from the scene or parent node or whatever your `didBeginContact` is a member of.

Make `planet` a class variable and in `didBeginContact`, call `planet.removeAllActions()`

Comment: That was the answer. Thanks!!